# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, Order Not syncing to ERP. Anyone to know about this issue?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am currently working on Magento store(2.2.5 enterprize), this store is integrated with Microsoft Dynamics AX ERP. I have faced an issue regarding syncing of order's data with Dynamics ERP. When I updated customer_id in sales_order table then an error occurred "The Order Not syncing to ERP"

Comment: In your title, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, I've seen when Visual Studio's cache is screwed up. I recall deleting a bunch of cache files and/or running a command to get it fixed. The rest of your question though, no clue.

Comment: magento store is integrated with Microsoft Dynamics AX. When I update customer data in magento store's table, this issue occurred in dynamics ax

Comment: Sounds like you will need developer assistance to debug your integrations!